# NPCD: ERROR: Executed command exits with return code '255'

Tags: perl, nagios, icinga2

After updating modules in `cpan` pnp4nagios/NPCD started logging the following in my syslog every time the script was called;

```
NPCD[19673]: ERROR: Executed command exits with return code '255'
NPCD[19673]: ERROR: Command line was '/etc/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl -n --bulk /var/spool/icinga2/perfdata/host-perfdata.1524923929'
```

There didn't appear to be any loss in functionality or data and my graphs where populating as expected - but I was being spammed by this.

Running the script from the cli gave this result;

```
bash-4.1$ /etc/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl -n --bulk /var/spool/icinga2/perfdata/host-perfdata.1524919009 
tv_interval() 2nd argument should be an array reference at /etc/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl line 218, <PDFILE> line 111
```

The only useful [google](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwikwOm9kt3aAhUDalAKHa-ZCLYQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fperldoc.perl.org%2FTime%2FHiRes.html&usg=AOvVaw25hDFmDe0Kc6NnsmDjneL6) result to that error points at the `Time::HiRes` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the current version of `Time::HiRes` was/is the issue. `cpan` offers `Time-HiRes-1.9758` as an update but this appears to be the version causing the issue.

In order to stop the error I had to downgrade that module by doing the following;

`make clean` in the folder of the installed version (Mine was at `.cpan/build/Time-HiRes-1.9758`) then fetching the specific version from cpan;

`cpan JHI/Time-HiRes-1.9721.tar.gz` which installed the older (1.9721) version.

Restarted `npcd` and the errors where gone.

I'm not sure which version of `Time-HiRes` introduced this error/change in behaviour as I've not been through them and am not 100% certain where the issue may actually lay (npcd/Time-HiRes/somewhere else). Hopefully this points someone else in the right direction.

From [ikegami's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) comment

> "Even in version 1.9721, the second argument (if provided), must be an
>   array reference. It seems the only change in behaviour is the addition
>   of input validation. `process_perfdata.pl` is buggy, and newer
>   versions of `Time::HiRes` let you know it."

Comment: Even in [version 1.9721](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/Time-HiRes-1.9721/HiRes.pm), the second argument (if provided), must be an array reference. It seems the only change in behaviour is the addition of input validation. `process_perfdata.pl` is buggy, and newer versions of Time::HiRes let you know it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem even in the latest version of pnp4nagios. 
If you need a quick workaround you can modify the pnp4nagios script process_perfdata.pl so that it does always pass an array reference, as follows (diff output):

```
 sub main {
     my $job = shift;
     my $t0 = [gettimeofday];
-    my $t1;
+    my @t1=();
+    my $t1=\@t1;
     my $rt;
     my $lines = 0;
     # Gearman Worker
```

I've done this and it seems to work ok and remove the very frequent error message. I'll post back here if it seems to cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the newest library Time:HiRes 1.9758 and the second value from tv_interval bounds. According to manual if ommited, the actual time is used - what is exactly what it does. So you need to apply this command to script process_perfdata.pl:

sed -s 's/tv_interval $t0, $t1/tv_interval $t0/g' -i process_perfdata.pl

After that everything will work as it should.
I experienced the problem with CentOS8 which is not providing older versions of HiRes library. Another symptom is that npcd cannot create .pnp-internal folder.